# Regex to validate date between 1956 to 2002

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to use regex to validate date between 1956 to 2002.

Example:

11/12/1956 - Pass
11/12/1955 - Fail
11/12/2002 - Pass
11/12/2020 - Fail

Here is what I have so far.

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19?[5-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9][0-9][0-2])$
```

Challenge is on how to validate year value more than 1956.

Any idea on how to go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why with a regexp? Would be really easy using the built in `Date` class or `moment.js`

Comment: I know about moment.js but I might be possible here. Available options are only regex to validate various inputs. Moment.js might come in later as per the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this regex:  `^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]((19([6-9]\d|5[6-9]))|200[0-2])$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZtJ4RK/23) here

Comment: down vote without comment?

Comment: @Cheruiyot Felix is this answer ok for you? if its not help you i will delete this..

Comment: Thank you Golam. This works perfect. I'm altered the first part to fix ensure the date is always in the format 01/01/2000 for example. Here is my final: ^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]((19([6-9]\d|5[6-9]))|200[0-2])$

Comment: This doesn't match `10/05/1960` but matches `30/02/1975`

Comment: @Edric i gave demo... in right side their is better explaination.. but it will be good if i gave explaination.. thanks

Comment: But still - links can go down or be taken down at any point in time and providing the explanation in the answer itself is more convenient without having to head to an external link or for people who are unable to access the demo for reasons such as poor internet or proxies preventing them from accessing.